Как убрать задержку при бинде клавиш на джаве?
Как убрать период игнорирования удержания клавиши? То есть при удержании клавиши она 1 раз нажала, на пол секунды зависла, а потом продолжила.
frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() { 
    @Override public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { 
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            if (pl1y < 380) {
                pl1y += 11;
                player1.setBounds(0, pl1y, 17, 80);
            }
        } 
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            if (pl1y > 5) {
                pl1y -= 11;
                player1.setBounds(0, pl1y, 17, 80);
            }           
        } 

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            if (pl2y < 380) {
                pl2y += 11;
                player2.setBounds(970, pl2y, 17, 80);
            }
        } 

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            if (pl2y > 5) {
                pl2y -= 11;
                player2.setBounds(970, pl2y, 17, 80);
            }           
        } 
    } 
});


Наверно надо смотреть в настройки клавиатуры?

Клавиатурой управляет операционная система. Что-то можно поправить в настройках ОС.

В играх то нет задержки.

Подозреваю, что вопрос был про получение повторных событий нажатия клавиши при ее удержании.

непонятна суть вопроса. в момент нажатия клавиши генерируется событие нажатия, в момент отпускания - событие отпускания. ну, по крайней мере в xorg. там, где не используется xorg, вряд ли как-то по-другому сделано.

Мне нужно, что бы при удержании клавиши условие исполнялось равномерно, а не -__--------    - это нажатие,   _ это пропуск. Мне нужно этот пропуск убрать.

при нажатии клавиши генерируется KeyDown эвент, при отпускании KeyUp.
Если в этот промежуток времени нужно совершать какое-то переодическое действие, то не стоит пологатся на события от клавиатуры. Лучше использоавать таймер.
